# How to create only once my static list when create my object again and again

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an class and one of the class members is static list that keep all my object and i only want to create this list `(List<myObject> list = new ...)` once.
what is the best way to do it ?

```
public class MyObject
{
    private string _name;
    private static List<Capture> _list;

    public MyObject(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        _list.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: put it in it's own static class

Comment: But i want to create this class instance again and again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would put it in the class's static constructor or instantiate it inline.

```
public class MyObject
{
    private string _name;
    // inline
    // private static List<Capture> _list = new List<Capture>();

    // if via static constructor
    private static List<Capture> _list;

    static MyObject() 
    {
        _list = new List<Capture>();
    }

    public MyObject(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        _list.Add(this);
    }
}
```

[MSDN C# Static Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) for further reading.

Comment: What is the different between static MyObject() and public MyObject(string name) ? when u create MyObject instance what happen ?

Comment: @user2214609 the static constructor is only called once when the class is first accessed, and since it is static, it can only access static members.

Comment: And which of the 2 options is batter ? (class's static constructor or instantiate it inline)

Comment: @user2214609:  Whichever you like.  Instantiating inline is less code.

Answer (score 3):

To me this is the best way:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private static readonly List<Capture> _list = new List<Capture>();
}
```

Comment: Good to remember `readonly` when he wants to create the list only once.

Comment: @Alessandro: One irrelevant question to the OP's question: Is this form of initializing _list equivalent to the static constructor when compiled? When is this initializing called?

Comment: @Alireza Yes, this is equivalent.

Comment: There is differences between inline and constructor, the difference is in when the field is initialized take a look at http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria That would be true of an instance constructor, but not a static constructor, and in any event, would not be an issue for a case this simple.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a thread safe [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) here,

> You can use one of the simple constructors whose default behavior is to create a thread-safe Lazy object, so that only one instance of the lazily instantiated object is created no matter how many threads try to access it.

```
private static Lazy<List<Capture>> _list = 
        new Lazy<List<Capture>>(() =>
        {
            //fill your list
            return list;
        }, true);
```

You can find a more detailed explanation [here (Lazy and the Singleton Design Pattern)](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx) or [here (http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

Comment: This is way more work than it needs to be.  Just create the new list inline instead...

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize it inline.  C# guarantees that static objects will only be initialized once before the are accessed.

```
public class MyObject
{
    private string _name;
    private static List<Capture> _list = new List<Capture>();

    public MyObject(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        _list.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As all previous responses mentioned all possible approaches like static ctor or static block I have to ponder the purpose.

According to separation of concerns or single responsibility pattern, there should be another class which would contain list of all implementations, not implementation itself even in a static way. Simplest solution is to use factory (not factory method) along with package visible ctor and store those instances in there.